# set background image from dropdown menu - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a menu to select different backgrounds for a website about my artwork.

This (link  works perfectly for just background colors and I was able to replicate it just fine.
http://www.javascripter.net/faq/backgrou.htm

I know that the property is bgImg but I just can't figure out how to implement it. If anybody could make a simple jsfiddle to show me this seemingly simple trick I'd be really grateful.

Thanks!
Rollin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, just add more options to the dropdown with the image url as the value to give more background options.

HTML:

```
<select id="backgrounds">
    <option>Select a background</option>
    <option value="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT-wQk0CTwl93EmiaUaoIjpMVmwHDNBz_7hN0UNpAz5DCWq66Sp-w">Background 1</option>
    <option value="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/abstract_color_background_picture_8016-wide.jpg">Background 2</option>    
</select>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var body = $(document.body);
    $('#backgrounds').bind('change', function(event){
        var bg = $(this).val();
        if(bg == null || typeof bg === 'undefined' || $.trim(bg) === '')
            body.css('background-image', '');
        else
            body.css('background-image', "url('" + bg + "')");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wg2AU/

To allow a combination of background images and background colors you can use the code below:

HTML:

```
<select id="backgrounds">
    <option>Select a background</option>
    <option value="url('http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT-wQk0CTwl93EmiaUaoIjpMVmwHDNBz_7hN0UNpAz5DCWq66Sp-w')">Background Image 1</option>
    <option value="url('http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/abstract_color_background_picture_8016-wide.jpg')">Background Image 2</option>
    <option value="none #000">Black</option>
    <option value="none red">Red</option>
</select>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var body = $(document.body);
    $('#backgrounds').bind('change', function(event){
        var bg = $(this).val();
        if(bg == null || typeof bg === 'undefined' || $.trim(bg) === '')
            body.css('background', 'none transparent');
        else
            body.css('background', bg);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hKBtp/4/

Answer (score 1):

[<kbd>jsFiddle Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/uA9PB/2/)

With background image options instead of just colors.

```
<form name="bgcolorForm">View my artwork:
    <select name="backArt" id="backArt">
        <option value="image1.gif">A Wedding Photo</option>
        <option value="image2.jpg">Beautiful Sunset</option>
        <option value="image3.gif">Canyon Lights</option>
        <option value="image4.gif">Morning Dew</option>
        <option value="image5.jpg">My Wife's Ugly Wart</option>
        <option value="image6.gif">My Beautiful Children</option>
    </select>
</form>

$(function () {
    $('#backArt').on('change', function () {
        var backImg = $('option:selected', this).val();
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + backImg + ')');
    });
});
```