# Run a js function onchange()

Tags: javascript, html

This seems like a simple problem, but I don't get why it's not working for me. I have a dropdown menu and image. The image changes based on what is selected in the dropdown menu, but I don't understand why my function isn't being triggered.

```
<select onchange="changeImage()" id="samples">
            <option value="Cpp">C++ Example</option>
            <option value="Mobile">Mobile Applications Example</option>
</select>
```

and the javascript

```
<script>
        function changeImage()
        {
            var selection = document.getElementById("samples");

            var image = document.getElementById("shown");

            if(selection.value == "Cpp")
            {
            image.src="images/CppCoursesCapture.JPG";
            }
            else if(selection.value == "Mobile")
            {
            image.src="images/MobileQuizCapture.JPG";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

The function doesn't change the image though

EDIT: missed some perenthesis

Comment: In IE, if the user navigates the options using the cursor keys, the change listener will be called each time the selection changes. Other browsers will wait until the the selected option actually changes.

Answer (score 2):

#### [A lovely jsbin.com demo](http://jsbin.com/EGUYUdoy/3/edit)

You should take a less obtrusive approach

```
<select id="samples">
  <option value="Cpp" data-image="images/CppCoursesCapture.JPG">C++ Example</option>
  <option value="Mobile" data-image="images/MobileQuizCapture.JPG">Mobile Applications Example</option>
</select>
```

Then in JavaScript

```
// implementation
function updateImage() {
  var selected = this.options[this.selectedIndex];

  var image = document.getElementById("shown");
  image.src = selected.getAttribute("data-image");
}

// target SELECT
var elem = document.getElementById("samples");

// change event
elem.addEventListener("change", function(event){
  updateImage.call(this);
});

// initialization
updateImage.call(elem);
```

Comment: @BlueSkies, that would pass an unwanted `event` argument in my `updateImage` function. Notice I specifically wrote `updateImage.call(this)` and **not** `updateImage.call(this, event)`. Thanks for the review, though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your conditions in parenthesis:

```
if (selection.value == "Cpp")
```

..and...

```
else if (selection.value == "Mobile")
```

If you run your developer tools, it will pick up that your syntax is incorrect.. and breaking the script.

Comment: Yea, I just caught that one, though it still doesn't change the image when fixed

Comment: Remember that, without a leading forward slash `/`, your paths are relative to the current directory. If the `images` folder is at the root of your site.. put a leading forward slash at the start. E.g: `/images/MobileQuizCapture.JPG`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeImage()
        {
            alert("Function Called");
            var selection = document.getElementById("samples");

            var image = document.getElementById("shown");

            if (selection.value == "Cpp")
            {
            image.src="images/CppCoursesCapture.JPG";
            }
            else if( selection.value == "Mobile")
            {
            image.src="images/MobileQuizCapture.JPG";
            }
        }
```

forgot brackets ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest storing the path to the image as the value for the option and using that to change the image src. The following shows how to do this for a background image but it can be easily adapted for an image tag.

The advantage of doing it this way is that you can simply add more options to the select and they will work without needing to modify the javascript.

[set background image from dropdown menu - javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555410/set-background-image-from-dropdown-menu-javascript/19555530#19555530)

```
<select id="samples">
    <option>Select an image</option>
    <option value="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT-wQk0CTwl93EmiaUaoIjpMVmwHDNBz_7hN0UNpAz5DCWq66Sp-w">C++ Example</option>
    <option value="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/abstract_color_background_picture_8016-wide.jpg">Mobile Applications Example</option>
</select>
<img id="image" />


$(document).ready(function()
{
    var image = $('#image');
    $('#samples').bind('change', function(event){
        var img = $(this).val();
        if(img == null || typeof img === 'undefined' || $.trim(img) === '')
            image.removeAttr('src');
        else
            image.attr('src', img);
    });
});
```

Here is a JS fiddle illustrating how to do this for your purposes:

http://jsfiddle.net/hKBtp/5/

Comment: I don't see a jQuery tag on the question. The value of a select element should never be either null or undefined, it should only have a string value (though it may be an empty string). So the only test above that makes any sense is `img == ''`. It would be more sensible if that variable had a name like `selectValue`. Oh, the *src* attribute for *img* elements is mandatory, so removing it creates invalid markup that will likely be corrected by the browser, so removing it doesn't seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys, my issue was the->

```
if selection.value = cpp
```

instead I missed the parenthesis and quotations

```
if(selection.value = "cpp")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/yQBz7/1/

```
<script>
    function changeImage()
    {
        var selection = document.getElementById("samples");

        var image = document.getElementById("shown");

        if(selection.value == "Cpp")
        {
        image.innerHTML="<img src='http://www.techiesin.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/c-logo.jpg' />";
        }
        else if(selection.value == "Mobile")
        {
        image.innerHTML="<img src='http://www.truste.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/MobileAppDevelopments1.jpeg' />";
        }
    }
</script>
```